# A question about integral transformation from the Unit sphere to Euclidean space.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, vector-analysis, spherical-coordinates

I want to show the following identity about integral on spherical coordinate system:

Let $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ denote the unit sphere of the Euclidean space $(\mathbb{R}^d,||\cdot||)$ equipped with
the surface Lebesgue measure $\sigma$ normalized by $\sigma(\mathbb{\mathbb{S}}^{d-1}) = 1$.  Prove that for $1\leq q<\infty$:

$$\Big(\int_{\mathbb{s}^{d-1}}|x\cdot y|^qd\sigma(y)\Big)^{1/q} = ||x||_2\Big(\frac{2\Gamma(d/2)}{\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma((d-1)/2)}  \int_{0}^1 x_1^q(1-x_1^2)^{\frac{d-3}2} dx_1\Big)^{1/q},$$

where $||x||_2=(\sum_{i=1}^d|x_i|^2)^{1/2}$.

**My understanding** is that this identity transfers the integral about sphere to integral about one variable $x_1$. I feel that this  maybe using the rotation invariance of the measure $d\sigma$ and doing the spherical coordinate transformation. But I have no idea to prove this identity.

Any suggestions would be welcome and thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to construct a proof. Your intuition is correct, but doing a rotation in spherical coordinates can be a bit problematic, albeit probably doable. A solution to this is to rewrite the expression as an integral over $\mathbb{R}^d$ and do the rotation there, where it's pretty easy to express explicitly.

Rewrite the original integral as
$$I=\int_{S^{d-1}}|x\cdot y|^qd\sigma_y=\mu^{-1}(S_{d-1})\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}d^d y~\delta(||y||_2-1)|x\cdot y|^q$$
Now perform an arbitrary rotation in $y$ expressed as a change of variables $y'=Ry~,~ R^TR=I~,~d^dy'=d^dy$. The integral now reads
$$I=\frac{1}{\mu(S_{d-1})}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}d^d y'~\delta(||y'||_2-1)|(Rx)^T y'|^q$$
Keeping in mind that we want to introduce [multidimensional spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_volume_and_area_elements) eventually, we pick $Rx=||x||_2\hat{e_1}$. This is always possible. With this choice $(Rx)^T y'=||x||_2||y'||_2\cos\varphi_1$ and finally reintroducing spherical coordinates we obtain
$$I=\frac{||x||^q}{\mu(S_{d-1})}\int_0^{\infty} dr  ~r^n\delta(r-1)\int d\Omega_{d-1}|\cos\varphi_1|^q$$
The radial integral is, as expected, trivial. The angular integral can be expressed in terms of the spherical surface element as
$$\int d\Omega_{d-1}|\cos\varphi_1|^q=\int d\Omega_{d-2}\int_{0}^{\pi}d\varphi_1|\cos\varphi_1|^q\sin^{d-2}\varphi_1=2\mu(S_{d-2})\int_0^{\pi/2}d\varphi_1\cos^{q}\varphi_1\sin^{d-2}\varphi_1=2\mu(S_{d-2})\int_{0}^1dx_1 ~x_1^q(1-x_1^2)^{\frac{d-3}{2}}$$
where the last step above has been achieved by setting $x_1=\cos\varphi_1$. Substituting in the known values for the surface area of the spheres we get the desired result
$$I=||x||^q\frac{2\Gamma\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi}~\Gamma\left(\frac{d-1}{2}\right)}\int_{0}^1 dx_1~ x_1^q(1-x_1^2)^{\frac{d-3}{2}}$$
**PS** the last integral can be done in terms of Gamma functions as well!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you explain in the line 6, what is the $d^dy$ and $\delta(||y||_2-1)$ mean? How you get them?

Comment: My understanding is that $d^dy$ means the $dy$ in the d-dimension and $\delta$ is the Dirac function implies we only consider $||y||_2=1$. Am I correct? Besides, could you explain how to rewrite the original integral as the integral w.r.t $\mathbb{R}^d$? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The product of these two is the definition of $d\sigma(y)$ when the sphere is embedded in $\mathcal{R}^d$ (modulo a constant, which was imposed by the normalization of the measure of the sphere). I chose to go in to that embedding space because everything is written in terms of that space's inner product so it is expected that there the calculation will be easier. The delta function restricts the integral on the sphere.

Comment: Ok, many thanks for the clarification! Just one more question that the $\Omega_{d-1}$ is the spherical coordinates in $R^{d-1}$?